# multiple key has multiple values combine values

Tags: python

File1:

```
chrom   start   end strand  gene_id gene_name
1   4763414 4764404 -   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
1   4764597 4767606 -   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
1   4764597 4766491 -   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
1   4766882 4767606 -   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
1   4767729 4772649 -   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
1   4767729 4768829 -   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
1   4767729 4775654 -   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
1   4772382 4772649 -   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
1   4772814 4774032 -   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
1   4772814 4774159 -   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
1   4772814 4775654 -   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
1   4772814 4774032 +   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
1   4774186 4775654 -   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
1   4774186 4775654 +   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
1   4774186 4775699 -   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
1   4775960 4798536 +   ENSMUSG00000025903  Lypla1
1   4831213 4857551 +   ENSMUSG00000025903  Lypla1
1   4831213 4857551 +   ENSMUSG00000033813  Tcea1
```

desired output:

```
chrom   start   end strand  gene_id gene_name
    1   4763414 4764404 -   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
    1   4764597 4767606 -   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
    1   4764597 4766491 -   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
    1   4766882 4767606 -   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
    1   4767729 4772649 -   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
    1   4767729 4768829 -   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
    1   4767729 4775654 -   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
    1   4772382 4772649 -   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
    1   4772814 4774032 -   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
    1   4772814 4774159 -   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
    1   4772814 4775654 -   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
    1   4772814 4774032 +   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
    1   4774186 4775654 -   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
    1   4774186 4775654 +   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
    1   4774186 4775699 -   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
    1   4775960 4798536 +   ENSMUSG00000025903  Lypla1
    1   4831213 4857551 +   ENSMUSG00000025903,ENSMUSG00000033813   Lypla1,Tcea1
```

In this case the last line has two values merged in one column that belong to "1    4831213 4857551 +"  sometimes it may be more than two what would be an ideal way to approach this?

```
   file2["chrom"].update(dict(zip(["start", "end", "strand"]
```

is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [default dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to merge your combinations. The dict key can be a joined string matching your 'multiple value' criteria:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = """chrom   start   end strand  gene_id gene_name
1   4774186 4775699 -   ENSMUSG00000033845  Mrpl15
1   4775960 4798536 +   ENSMUSG00000025903  Lypla1
1   4831213 4857551 +   ENSMUSG00000025903  Lypla1
1   4831213 4857551 +   ENSMUSG00000033813  Tcea1"""

result = defaultdict(list)
headers = ""

for i, line in enumerate(data.splitlines()):
    if i == 0:
        headers = line.split()
    else:
        d = dict(zip(headers, line.split()))

        key = '%(chrom)s_%(start)s_%(end)s_%(strand)s' % d
        result[key].append(d)

for val in result.values():
    print (val)
```

Returns:

```
[{'chrom': '1', 'start': '4774186', 'end': '4775699', 'strand': '-', 'gene_id': 'ENSMUSG00000033845', 'gene_name': 'Mrpl15'}]
[{'chrom': '1', 'start': '4775960', 'end': '4798536', 'strand': '+', 'gene_id': 'ENSMUSG00000025903', 'gene_name': 'Lypla1'}]
[{'chrom': '1', 'start': '4831213', 'end': '4857551', 'strand': '+', 'gene_id': 'ENSMUSG00000025903', 'gene_name': 'Lypla1'}, {'chrom': '1', 'start': '4831213', 'end': '4857551', 'strand': '+', 'gene_id': 'ENSMUSG00000033813', 'gene_name': 'Tcea1'}]
```

Write to csv, you need to join the columns that need to be merged using join:

```
with open('write.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerow(headers)

    for vals in result.values():
        _finalRow = []

        for h in headers:
            if h not in ['gene_id', 'gene_name']:
                _finalRow.append(vals[0][h])  # regular columns
            else:
                _finalRow.append(','.join([v[h] for v in vals]))  # merge columns

        writer.writerow(_finalRow)
```

Comment: that looks interesting never used it, how can i write the output to a csv or text file

Comment: Not able to write it out to a csv file `for val in result.values():
    print (val)
with open('write.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f) 
    for k,v in result.iteritems():
        writer.writerow([k] + v)` not sure what is wrong may be there is a dffrent way to write default dict that I am not aware of , i am also missing headers in my csv

Comment: What did you try, to write to csv ?

Comment: output csv  `1_4775960_4798536_+ {'end': '4798536', 'gene_id': 'ENSMUSG00000025903', 'start': '4775960', 'strand': '+', 'chrom': '1', 'gene_name': 'Lypla1'} 
1_4831213_4857551_+ {'end': '4857551', 'gene_id': 'ENSMUSG00000025903', 'start': '4831213', 'strand': '+', 'chrom': '1', 'gene_name': 'Lypla1'} {'end': '4857551', 'gene_id': 'ENSMUSG00000033813', 'start': '4831213', 'strand': '+', 'chrom': '1', 'gene_name': 'Tcea1'}
1_4774186_4775699_- {'end': '4775699', 'gene_id': 'ENSMUSG00000033845', 'start': '4774186', 'strand': '-', 'chrom': '1', 'gene_name': 'Mrpl15'} `

Comment: @sbradbio probably easiest to store as [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) or use _pandas_ `to_csv()` if you need a csv, [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) .

Comment: @patrick my problem is this line `{'end': '4857551', 'gene_id': 'ENSMUSG00000025903', 'start': '4831213', 'strand': '+', 'chrom': '1', 'gene_name': 'Lypla1'} {'end': '4857551', 'gene_id': 'ENSMUSG00000033813', 'start': '4831213', 'strand': '+', 'chrom': '1', 'gene_name': 'Tcea1'}` not sure hot to set first 4 columns and write it like this  `1   4831213 4857551 +   ENSMUSG00000025903,ENSMUSG00000033813   Lypla1,Tcea1`  any code snippet is much appreciated

Comment: @sbradbio I'm kinda busy right now, sorry, have you tried to 1) run it thru  dataframe from dict ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)) and 2) then output with the to_csv tool listed above.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer how can load a file instead of variable data i tried this `data = open(r'pathtofile/some.txt')` and i have this error `AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'splitlines'`